# Why state variable inside redux Reducer not not increment by 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I have a simple two button on the web page one for increment and one for decrements an integer.
[image]

Once i click on **+** button it will add 1 to the current value.

Below is my Reducer and i have wrapped **"INCREMENT"** with a `setTimeout` and when i click on **+** button i'am expecting to see **1** on the page after 2 secs, but it gives me **77** as soon as click happens without waiting for 2 secs, Why this happens, why 77 every time?

p.s. I might need a middleware to handle this async action, but i m trying to understand whats going on

Thank you

```
const mathReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return setTimeout(() => {
        state = state + 1
      }, 2000)
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default mathReducer
```

Comment: You are not returning state. And state is an object not a number

Comment: Thanks, but how it evaluates to 77 every time?

Comment: Could you please give the same code via jsfiddle, will look into it ?

Comment: will you please show the button code

Answer (score 2):

Because a reducer function works by deterministically *returning* the new value of the state, given the old state, and whatever action.

In your code you are just reassigning the state variable, with this line:

```
    state = state + 1
```

If what you want to do is update the state after 1 second, what I would do is use the setTimeout to defer triggering the 'update state' action.

Comment: Thanks nice approach to make it work, im trying to understand why it's evaluating to 77 everytime without as delay